# Поток строк удаляет предыдущее значение

Tags: c++, строки, потоки-данных

Почему программа выводит `12`, а не `112`?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::stringstream ss("1");
  std::cout << ss.str();
  ss << "2";
  std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

Comment: А почему программа должна выводить `112`?

Comment: @EOF потому что до записи 2 там было 1

Comment: Это поток,  не строка. Очевидно вывод 2. Читайте документацию

Comment: @icYFTL я не писал, что это строка. "Очевидно" - не ответ.

Comment: "В библиотеке IOStream есть также класс stringstream, который позволяет связать поток ввода-вывода со строкой в памяти. Всё, что выводится в такой поток, добавляется в конец строки; всё, что считывается из потока — извлекается из начала строки." Цитата [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/post/131977/)  Вы вывели данные из ss в cout. При этом они, как понимаю, удалились из ss

Comment: @EOF если в начале написать `ss << "1";` вместо конструктора с "1", то и будет выводить 112 при выводе данные не удаляются

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов ну так по такой цитате добавляем в конец и получаем "12", потом считываем сначала и получаем "1" или "12", но никак не просто "2".

Comment: @user7860670 почему так? Конструктор работает не так как << получается?

Comment: @carl при таком конструировании, позиция записи устанавливается в начало потока.

Comment: @Croessmah а при << в конец?

Comment: После создания stringstream поставь позицию на конец строки так ss.seekp(1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сохранения начального строкового значения для дозаписи в поток при вызове конструктора следует указывать режим дописывания в конец `app` или `ate`. По-умолчанию он использует режим перезаписи с начала (in out):

```
::std::stringstream ss
{
   "1"
,  ::std::ios_base::in bitor ::std::ios_base::out bitor ::std::ios_base::app
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/edbnW8

Comment: А по-умолчанию перезапись идёт получается?

Comment: @по-умолчанию там только in out

Comment: поток предназначен  для чтения и для записи, и есть только одно значение позиции. Для того, чтобы вы могли читать все что есть в буфере, позиция, по умолчанию, при конструировании устанавливается  в начало буфера, не зависимо от того, какой строкой вы сконструировали объект,. И, естественно, при записи, тоже начинается запись с начала. Поэтому и есть возможность  менять режим чтения и записи, что и сделано в этом ответе. *p.s.* Можно  не только списком инициализации конструировать...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а как ещё можно конструировать?

Comment: `std::stringstream ss("1", ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::app);`